# I could add an account to Citrix Receiver in Ubuntu but I can't start it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, citrix

I just installed successfully Citrix Receiver in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits by following these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo. I added the same account which I am using successfully in Windows machine via /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/configmgr &.
Nevertheless, I can't start it. I am quite new to Ubuntu. I tried these options:

1 attempt - browse to /usr/share/applications, find selfservice.desktop, right-click and click in run

2 attempt - search applications, find Citrix Receiver and launch it

3.1 attempt - check if there is "-" missed in /usr/share/applications/selfservice.desktop as suggested in http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/358076-deb-package-uses-icaroot-instead-of-icaroot-spelling-error/#entry1844542

3.2 attempt - try start selfservice.desktop via terminal:
deme@PC:/usr/share/applications$ sudo ./selfservice.desktop
[sudo] password for deme: 
sudo: ./selfservice.desktop: command not found

3.3 attempt - try start selfservice via terminal:
deme@PC:/opt/Citrix/ICAClient$ sudo ./selfservice
libwebkit: libwebkit-1.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dir

Comment: I am really stuck on this: "how can I start citrix receiver client in Ubuntu"? I guess I have installed correctly since I was able to add an account but I can't start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully it can be useful to someone in future. After I did two actions, I am able to start Citrix Receiver:
1 - I follow the recommendation: 8. Configure Firefox In Firefox, go to Tools -> Add-ons -> Plugins, and make sure the "Citrix Receiver for Linux" plugin is set to "Always Activate". 
2 - In Firefox, on Add-ons Manager session, I looked for the most recent Citrix Receiver and then I choose "Full Package (Self-Service Support)" in  https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html